# Navigation menu width when browser is resized

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, menu

I have the following equation for which I don't have a resolution :)
I need a navigation menu that is simply composed from

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li>
      <a>link</a>
        </li>
other 20 li's ...and last a select which contains li's that no longer have space on menu ...
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a>last li's that cannot be displayed on nav menu </a>
            </li>
       </ul>
    </ul>
```

How can I do that?? and on window resize when menu width is resized  li's go on last select and on expand goes back on menu.

If someone can help me with a nice jQuery for this please.

thank you

Comment: Your markup is not according to w3c standards. A `ul` tag only has `li` tags.

Comment: Your Question is not even clear brother

Comment: @A.K,@feeela :sorry fellas that <select></select> is actually an <ul></ul> my equation was described wrong, i just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML code isn't valid so I'm trying to read between the lines.

Two possible solutions to look at.

[TinyNav.js](http://tinynav.viljamis.com/).

It won't do it quite as you have described, however it will turn a list into a select automatically through media queries. Normally this is to make the menu friendly on small screens.

20 list items is too many to show in my opinion, in which case trying to move to a smaller number with submenu items is a good way to go. You show the sub-menu items though [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/). Not a select, but arguably better as the submenu items appear on hovering over the parent item.

Comment: Thank you Ben, I will play a little bit with tinyNav. Yes I know but is a client decision , not mine :) thank's again

Answer (score 1):

use the window.onresize DOM event

```
window.onresize = function(event) {

 your code for changing content of ul goes here     

}
```